# Use ServiceStack's IAuthRepository to get detailed information

Tags: servicestack

I would like to get a user's information. I think that IAuthRepository can be used to retrieve information, but when I send insert the Id of user it does not return anything. I have the following code.

```
public UserService(IDbConnectionFactory db)
 {
     this._db = db;
     this._authRepository = HostContext.AppHost.GetAuthRepository(base.Request);
}
```

I intend to allow admins to get access the information from all users and regular uses should only have access to their own profile. In the code below I try to extract the detailed information from the user which is logged in (just an example) I can see that user contains the information, but test remains empty. I was thinking that the IAuthRepository has to be connected in some other manner.

```
[Authenticate]
public object Get(GetUser request)
{
     using (var db = _db.Open())
     {
         var session = this.SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();
         var user = Mapper.Map<UserDto>(session);
         var test = this._authRepository.GetUserAuthDetails(session.UserAuthId);
         return new GetUserResponse {Results = user };

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unnecessary to inject the `IDbConnectionFactory` into your own Services as you would typically use the `base.Db` and `base.AuthRepository` properties on the Service which are [Multitenancy-aware](https://docs.servicestack.net/multitenancy). Also note that the `db` you're opening in your Services is also unnecessary as it's never being used.

The 2 main User tables in an Auth Repository are a `UserAuth` which is the main table and `UserAuthDetails` which holds additional information from external providers for users that have signed up with OAuth.

You likely want to return both:

```
[Authenticate]
public object Get(GetUser request)
{
    var session = SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();
    return new GetUserResponse {
        User = AuthRepository.GetUserAuth(session.UserAuthId),
        UserDetails = AuthRepository.GetUserAuthDetails(session.UserAuthId)
    };
}
```

If it's still not returning anything, look at the `session.UserAuthId` used and the `UserAuth` and `UserAuthDetails` tables in your backend Auth Repository.

Comment: I see. So my guess is now that UserAuthDetails are only populated when it has to? Because it is empty.

Comment: @AtleKristiansen It's populated when users sign in with OAuth providers where it persists external info about Users that are provided by the external OAuth provider.